# How can I change nginx ports to go to a subdirectory?

Tags: nginx

I know how to change nginx ports, even though they don't work after I restart.

Let's say my website is `https://example.com`.

If I go to `example.com:1337`, how can I get it to go to a directory, like `/usr/share/nginx/html/theportfolder/`?

I googled this however nothing came up that helps me, just how can can change it from port 80 (I'm using port 443).

Answer (score 0):

Mapping a unique document root to a different port is accomplished by defining a new server block. A minimal example being this:

```
server {
    listen 1337;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html/theportfolder;
}
```

See [this](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html) for more.

Comment: When I do that I get the following error "An error occurred during a connection to example.com:1337. SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length. (Error code: ssl_error_rx_record_too_long) "

Comment: @AmiconInteractive The minimal example above is for HTTP. For HTTPS you will need to add some `ssl_` directives. See [this](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html) for more.